# When choosing plan, does it matter?

Tags: user-accounts

I can choose between Business Essentials, Business, Business Premium.

But does it really matter? Everyone in my firm will be given a vareity of licenses when it comes up and running?

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences between the plans, you can see them outlined here, https://products.office.com/en-us/business/compare-office-365-for-business-plans.

For example, Essential users do not get access to Office client, whereas Office Business users do not get email. It is up to you to decide what is important in your subscription to Office 365.

Comment: I see that. But when I'm choosing from there - the subsciption I'm choosing now is ONLY for the company admin right? So when adding more users along the line, I can choose them individually right?